# Found a weird malware at weird location (Windows Defender -Detected : Trojan:BAT/MineBicoin.K & -Affected Item: boot:\\.\E:\)

Tags: windows-10, boot, malware, trojan, cryptomining

I was using Ubuntu 20.04 (no dual boot) and after that I installed Official Windows 10 2020 version (even checked sha256sum of the iso file it was genuine) and then after it booted (partition remade and it was brand new fresh install, except my backup partition which is F: drive)

So as the Windows 10 booted, installed and came to life I did check Windows Defender everything was green and fine then I checked "Protection History" and it showed me with 2 messages "Remediation incomplete        [severe]"

When I expanded it that showed me details.

Windows Defender

**Protection History**

**Remediation Incomplete**.....[Severe^]

Detected: Trojan:BAT/MineBicoin.K

Status: Failed

This threat or app might not be completely remediated

Date: 15-07-2020 17:59

Details: This program is dangerous and executes commands from an
attacker.

**Affected Items:**

boot:\.\E:\

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RQfd.png)

I want to know about if this posses me any risk and even if not then how to remove it. What is that infected item location.

Comment: Sounds like a false positive

Comment: Go for avira or bitdefender for advanced analysis and remove the possibility of false positive. Both are free. Then update the question with the result.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta I did try the following AV Scans 1.Kaspersky Lab Antivirus Scanner 2.Malwarebyte 3.Hitmanpro 4. TDSSKiller and few more none found anything. Scans were all clean.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. But I don't have any idea about how to remove it from showing. I tried "Reset" button in app setting of "Windows Security" it did nothing.

Comment: What actions are you able to do?

Comment: Just allow and nothing (and im not looking forward to allow it).

Comment: Can you tell me what that boot: \\.\E:\ means

Comment: And in question the line below Affected Item my input in formatting question is same as written above in comments(i.e boot: \\.\E:\) But output after question is formatted isn't reflecting as boot: \\.\E:\ it is reflecting as boot: \.\E:\. But it was just to let you know Anyways can you please tell me that what that path or object actually is.

Comment: Low level format the drive (zero fill) then reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Moab I will consider that last resort. Is there any other option to manually do it.

Comment: That Malware was due to KMS Activation reinstalling windows solved the problem.

Comment: Sleep issue is due to hardware problem in Lid sensor it evokes with jerk or palm rest pressure.